# How to change background image and it's properties with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How can I change not only background image but also set additional properties?

Meaning, I have this code, that works fine:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = "url('image.png')";
```

But this fails:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = "url('image.png') no-repeat center center";
```

How can I add the additional properties to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you just need to change style.background properly if you want to set all values at once look here at the bottom http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundrepeat.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the additional properties are part of a short cut in CSS, which are applied using the `background` property so your js should be

```
document.getElementById(id).style.background = "url('image.png') no-repeat center center";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I new there was some short change needed to get it working right.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById("div3").style.backgroundPosition = "20% 50%";` - for position

```
document.getElementById("div3").style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat-y"; - for repeat
```

This will work for you